# Three Coloring of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that we have a graph $G = (V,N)$ and it is know that $G$ is three colorable. We also know that that there are distinct vertices $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$ and $n_4$ in $G$.

We know that there is a valid $3$ coloring of $G$ where vertices $n_1$ and $n_2$ are assigned the same color. We also know that there is a valid $3$ coloring of $G$ where vertices $n_3$ and $n_4$ are assigned the same color. Does this imply that there is a coloring of $G$ such that $n_1$ and $n_2$ are assigned the same color and $n_3$ and $n_4$ are assigned the same color?

Bob

Comment: I assume that $n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4$ are all distinct?

Comment: @BrianTung You are correct

Comment: @BrianTung By correct, do you mean the answer to my question is yes?

Comment: I didn't say "correct," you did! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample with $6$ vertices and $8$ edges.

First consider the $2$-chromatic graph $H=P_2+P_3$ with vertices $u_1,u_2,w_1,w_2,w_3$ and edges $u_1u_2,w_1w_2,w_2w_3.$ Note that there is a proper $2$-coloring of $H$ where vertices $u_1$ and $w_1$ are assigned the same color, and there is also a proper $2$-coloring of $H$ where vertices $u_2$ and $w_3$ are assigned the same color, but there is no proper $2$-coloring of $H$ such that $u_1$ and $w_1$ are assigned the same color and vertices $u_2$ and $w_3$ are assigned the same color.

Let $G$ be the $3$-chromatic graph obtained from $H$ by adding a new vertex $v$ and edges joining $v$ to all vertices of $H.$ Then there is a proper $3$-coloring of $G$ where vertices $u_1$ and $w_1$ are assigned the same color, and there is also a proper $3$-coloring of $G$ where vertices $u_2$ and $w_3$ are assigned the same color, but there is no proper $3$-coloring of $G$ such that $u_1$ and $w_1$ are assigned the same color and vertices $u_2$ and $w_3$ are assigned the same color.

Comment: Elegant counterexample

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is no. Consider the following graph, in which $n_1$ and $n_2$ are drawn as squares, and $n_3$ and $n_4$ are drawn as diamonds.

The left picture shows $n_3$ and $n_4$ with the same colors; the right shows $n_1$ and $n_2$ with the same colors. 
[image]

But the little assembly at the top ensures that $n_3$ and $n_2$ (the top diamond and the square just below it) have the same color, while the vertical line near the bottom ensures that $n_1$ and $n_4$ have different colors.

Comment: You can simplify the drawing above by removing the leftmost vertex (blue on the left), and the the green vertex slightly to its right. That destroys the symmetry, but it makes for a smaller counterexample: 9 edges, 8 vertices. You can probably go further, but ... a counterexample is a counterexample!

Comment: Excellent answer! Well done!